# Regex for all decimal numbers to match English format

Tags: java, regex

I do have a code that is responsible for replacing all String decimal values with comma separator into String decimal value with point separator, but not all cases are covered.

```
value.replaceAll(",(?=[0-9]+,)", "").replaceAll(",", ".")
```

52,52d => 52.52d

65.00f => 65.00f

123,50 => 123.50

1,234,567,89 => 1234567.89

1,234,567.89 => 1234.567.89 (BAD), should be 1234567.89

Comment: `value.replace(",", "#").replace(".", ",").replace("#", ".");`

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels The regex should return 1234567.89.

Comment: juste a small change for this regex `,(?=[0-9]+[,\\.])` seems to be working

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might first replace all the last comma's with a dot, and then replace the rest of the comma's with an empty string.

```
,(?=\d+[df]?(?!\S))
```

- `,` Match literally
- `(?=` Positive lookahead, assert what is directly to the right is

  - `\d+[df]?` Match 1+ digits and optional `d` or `f`
  - `(?!\S)` Assert a whitspace boundary to the right
- `)` Close lookahead

Example code:

```
String s = "52,52d\n"
        + "65.00f\n"
        + "123,50\n"
        + "1,234,567,89\n"
        + "1,234,567.89";

System.out.println(s
        .replaceAll(",(?=\\d+[df]?(?!\\S))", ".")
        .replaceAll(",", "")
);
```

Output

```
52.52d
65.00f
123.50
1234567.89
1234567.89
```

See a [Java demo](https://ideone.com/koxNEu)

---

If there is more text that can contain a comma and you don't want to replace those as a side effect, you can also first match all the parts where you want to do the replacements on and for those matches do the replacements.

```
\b\d+(?:\,\d+)*(?:\.\d+)?[fd]?\b
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/Y8QQvP/1)

Answer (score 1):

Replace last , with !, remove all commas, change ! to .

Answer (score 1):

You can replace the regex, `",(?=\\d+[df]?$)"` with `"."` and then chain the resulting string with `.replace(",", "")`.

**Demo:**

```
import java.util.stream.Stream;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        //Test
        Stream.of(
                    "52,52d",
                    "65.00f",
                    "123,50",
                    "1,234,567,89",
                    "1,234,567.89"
        ).forEach(s -> System.out.println(s + " => " + parse(s)));
    }
    static String parse(String s) {
        return s.replaceAll(",(?=\\d+[df]?$)", ".").replace(",", "");
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
52,52d => 52.52d
65.00f => 65.00f
123,50 => 123.50
1,234,567,89 => 1234567.89
1,234,567.89 => 1234567.89
```

[<kbd>ONLINE DEMO</kbd>](https://ideone.com/gW5pbN)

**Explanation of the regex:**

- `,`: The character literal, `,`
- `(?=\\d+[df]?$)`: Lookahead assertion for 1+ digit(s) optionally followed by `d` or `f` from the end of the string